# Code runs with namespace but not with using std::cout

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
  double degrees, radians;
  const double PI = 3.14159;

  cout << "Enter an angle in degrees and I will convert it\n";
  cout << "to radians for you: ";
  cin >> degrees;
  radians = degrees * PI / 180;

  cout << degrees << " degrees is equal to ";
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);
  cout << left << setw(7) << radians << "radians.\n ";
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get multiple errors related to undeclared manipulators but I have the #include  directive on top. However, if I replace the using std:: lines with just using namespace:std, the code runs fine.

Comment: [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55445795/10957435) should be it, but just to be thorough, what identifiers claim to be "unidentified"?

Comment: Joseph's answer is correct but, yes, for a good question please edit in all the pertinent details.

Answer (score 4):

`setw`, `fixed`, `setprecision`, and `left` are also in the `std` namespace, so you need to add `using` directives for all of them too.